# How to detect the close event of MMC 3.0 SnapIn written in C#

Tags: c#, mmc3

Folks, I am creating a MMC3.0 SnapIn program with C#. There I have some scope nodes and I have  FormViewDescription's where I used C# UserControl instances to display some data. And my intent is, user must see and update those data into the UserControl and there is a Save button onto that UserControl which user should press at the end of their editing and I will persist that change then.

Now the problem is,
If after making some changes, user closes the SnapIn window, all his changes are gone :( I need to prevent user before closing this window with a dialog that "Save before quiting " (or something like that - you know the standard feature of any editor program).
But could not found a way to do so. Any suggestions for me?

Would be appreciated much!

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I have also just created an MMC in much the same manner as you described above but after much searching (and frustration) I could not find any way to cancel the close event. I recommend changing your approach as explained below.

First of all have a look at how most of the MMC's that are already in Windows handle changing settings. Usually if you want to change a setting you select an item in a ListView and right-click 'Properties' to bring up a settings form and make your changes there.

Bringing up a form gives the developer the ability to control the full lifecycle of the form and ensure that settings are saved before it is closed.

**So my advice is:**

1. Create your FormView
2. Add any status information you need
3. Add a button 'Edit Settings' to your
   FormView
4. Create a Windows Form with
   Save/Cancel + all your data input
   controls
5. Launch your form with
   myForm.ShowDialog() when you click your 'Edit Settings' button
6. Handle the Save/Cancel button
   presses and cancel appropriately if
   data is dirty

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your reply. I know what you meant, and in fact, I also thought about a pop-up dialog based edit scenarios. But for my case, it's probably not possible because of the following reasons:

1. I have many nodes with their details pages. So it's would take a big amount of time to create popup edit page for each of them, also a read only page for general display.
2. Beside the double development efforts, my clients do not like pop-up dialogs to configure each nodes out there.

I can imagine, the frustration you had already, but good news for me is I finally resolved my problem.

Comment: How I resolved my problem :

I used an Native window interceptor to intercept the WindProc method for the parent SnapIn and only the child nodes that I am working with. Intercepting the WM_Close message, my solution just looks awesome. Just like a wordpad instance, it prompts before closing with yes, no, cancel and does what it needs to do, based on the user selection.

Happy programming and thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! I guess you used this class: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.wndproc.aspx
I don't know why I never found that during my search! If you get time, try and post a code sample as i'm sure someone else will one day benefit from this as well.

Comment: I have written a blog post with the code sample, so that anyone facing this same issue can find a work around.

BTW, thanks for your time to answer this thread.

Happy programming!

Comment: Here is the link :

http://moimtechview.blogspot.com/2010/08/prompt-for-save-changes-in-mmc-30.html